# How to show facebook login screen in my app?

Tags: android, facebook

In my app i gave options to user to login by using facebook application.

I am using `GRAPH` api for this it is working fine,

My problem is ,when user click facebook login icon,the login screen is opened like a dialog.

But i want to open like full login screen,like a facebook app login screen.

Through that i want get facebook login user details.

in myapp login screen is look like  [image]

But i want to login screen should be like this[image]

If any one know the solution,please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This screen will be shown only if the native application is installed in phone.

Try this code

```
public void connectToFacebook() {

    this.activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(
                this.getString(R.string.app_id)).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
    }
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
    openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) this);

    if (openRequest != null) {
        openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
        openRequest
                .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
        openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_stream"));
        openRequest.setCallback(callback);
        if (!activeSession.isOpened()) {
            activeSession.openForPublish(openRequest);
        }
    }
}
```